# How to support multiple versions of websphere mq?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have a Java application (which comunicate via JMS, connects using client mode) which need to support multiple versions of the websphere mq (v6,v7.1) (some clients want to remain on version 6 and others to upgrade to version 7). The problem can be solved if i will create two bundles with specific code/configuration for each version. But i want to avoid this. So there is a solution to avoid this problem?

For example to have the latest clients jar(v7) as dependency and work with older mq(v6) also or vice-versa?

Can somebody point me to some documentation which presents the compatibility between the client jars and mq versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MQ v7 clients can connect to MQ v6 queue manager. But note all features that are specific to V7 will not work when connecting V6 queue manager.

I would like remind you, MQ v6 is already out of support. You have to migrate to at least V7.0.1 and possibly latest fix pack.